# Access JMX via Golang

Tags: java, go, jmx

I need to access JMX of a running process via TCP. I can't install third party utilities on the machine such as Jolokia to make JMX accessible via HTTP. Is there a library that will let Golang speak JMX or Java RMI? Has a JMX client been implemented in any non-JVM language that I can use as inspiration for a Golang port? Both read and write access would be preferable but I'll settle for read-only.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if there is a way to talk to JMX in golang without jolokia. I've done it using the golokia project which I forked and made some changes.

Here it is, hope it helps.

https://github.com/joaoh82/golokia

Comment: This lib is a Jolokia wrapper, so it doesn't answer the question